# Is there a way to tell BigQuery that we're grouping by a unique identifier so that it won't demand aggregation on columns in the same table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have a table `tbl` in BigQuery which has a column `id` which indexes the table rows in a unique way, and another column `attr`. If I do

```
select tbl.id, tbl.attr
from
tbl
group by tbl.id
```

BigQuery throws the exception "SELECT references `tbl.attr` which is neither grouped nor aggregated"

I can do

```
select tbl.id, any_value(tbl.attr)
from
tbl
group by tbl.id
```

and this works, but if I want to select more columns from `tbl` after the group by, I have to write `any_value()` for each of those columns, which takes away from readability and might impact performance (?).

So is there a way to tell BigQuery "the thing we're grouping by is a unique identifier, there's no point in demanding aggregating after the other columns in the same table"?

Btw, of course this `group by` examples is useless, it's just for illustrative purposes, in application I would join with other tables and do aggregates on those but would still want to maintain columns from `tbl` other than `id`.

Edit: to consider a more "useful" example. Say I have a `clients` table with `client_id` and `city`. I have another table `orders` with orders placed by clients. I want to see a client's id, city and sum of orders placed.

```
select clients.client_id, any_value(clients.city), sum(orders.order_value)
from
clients
left join
orders
on
clients.client_id = orders.client_id
group by clients.client_id
```

or I could do

```
select 
clients_with_order_total.client_id, 
clients.city, 
clients_with_order_total.sum_order_total
( select
  clients.client_id, sum(orders.order_value) as sum_order_total
  from
  clients
  left join
  orders
  on
  orders.client_id = clients.client_id
  group by clients.client_id
) as clients_with_order_total
left join
clients
on
clients_with_order_total.client_id = clients.client_id
```

to avoid using `any_value()`, but this is an even more complex query than before.

Comment: You are talking about "SQL functional dependency". I don't think BigQuery implements that part of the SQL Standard. As far as I know, only PostgreSQL does implement it.

Comment: Why are you using GROUP BY with a unique id? Is there a use case that can’t be implemented using a (better) SQL construct? For example, your any_value statement could just be replaced by “select tbl.id, tbl.attr from tbl”

Comment: it is hard to answer questions based on "useless" examples! show real use case, present sample data and you will get answer [most likely]!

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant Thank you, I have added a real use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your real use case, the first SQL statement can just be re-written as:

```
select clients.client_id, clients.city, sum(orders.order_value)
from
clients
left join
orders
on
clients.client_id = orders.client_id
group by clients.client_id, clients.city
```

You don't need the "any_value(clients.city)", you just add "clients.city" to the GROUP BY clause